# I want to know the code to goto next activity when I press a button

Tags: java, android, button

I am a beginner in android studio. I want to know the code to go to the next activity when I press a button. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: You can check out guides for this. It is available in multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

Basic code would be:

```java
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }
      });
```